# Merging listed data.frames from a data.frame

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I'm querying data from the IMF using the package IMFData (https://github.com/mingjerli/IMFData).

The problem is that I do not know how to improve my code. There are 25 countries that I would like to extract data. I am sure my code is not the best to quickly create the desired dataframe (XDF, in my code).

```
library(IMFData)

databaseID <- "DOT"
startdate = "2013-01-01"
enddate = "2019-12-31"
checkquery = FALSE

queryfilter <- list(CL_FREQ = "M", CL_AREA_DOT = c("CA", "JP"), CL_INDICATOR_DOT = "TXG_FOB_USD", CL_COUNTERPART_AREA_DOT = "W00")
EXPORTS <- CompactDataMethod(databaseID, queryfilter, startdate, enddate, checkquery)

# I would like to improve this part:

XDF.1 <- EXPORTS$Obs[[1]]
XDF.2 <- EXPORTS$Obs[[2]]

XDF <- dplyr::left_join(XDF.1, XDF.2, by=c("@TIME_PERIOD"))

colnames(XDF) <- c("Date", "Canada", "Japan")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a base R approach that will get you all 227 areas with data.

First, get all the areas available with `DataStructureMethod`. Then split the list into sets of 25 areas so that the API won't fail. Create a new empty list to hold the returned data. Next, use a `for` loop to iterate over all the area sets and store the results into a list element.

```
library(IMFData)

databaseID <- "DOT"
startdate = "2013-01-01"
enddate = "2019-12-31"

areas <- DataStructureMethod("DOT")$CL_COUNTERPART_AREA_DOT$CodeValue
areas.list <- split(areas, ceiling(seq_along(areas)/25))

result.list <- list()
for(i in seq_along(areas.list)) {
  filter <- list(CL_FREQ = "M", CL_AREA_DOT = areas.list[[i]], CL_INDICATOR_DOT = "TXG_FOB_USD", CL_COUNTERPART_AREA_DOT = "W00")
  result.list[[i]] <- CompactDataMethod(databaseID, filter, startdate, enddate)
}
```

Now that we have all the data, we can extract the `@OBS_VALUE` from each area. So we can keep up with which is which, we will assign the column names to `@REF_AREA`. Then all we need to do is cbind all the areas together and add a time period column.

```
result <- sapply(result.list,function(x){y <- sapply(x$Obs,function(y){y[['@OBS_VALUE']]}); colnames(y) <- x[["@REF_AREA"]]; y})
result <- do.call(cbind,result)
result <- cbind(timeperiod = result.list[[1]]$Obs[[1]][['@TIME_PERIOD']],result)
result[1:10,1:10]
      timeperiod BB          BM         AF          BS           AL           AW          BD            BZ          AO           
 [1,] "2013-01"  "28.609779" "2.763473" "37.545734" "140.793072" "182.268383" "15.248257" "2135.314764" "26.993657" "5738.361548"
 [2,] "2013-02"  "31.408923" "2.588724" "23.319418" "51.207085"  "160.256056" "13.357883" "1883.921679" "31.959256" "5093.785673"
 [3,] "2013-03"  "26.490062" "2.161194" "34.313418" "116.533489" "187.347118" "11.807801" "2074.639533" "36.975964" "5836.777823"
 [4,] "2013-04"  "30.969022" "6.541486" "27.46926"  "79.9772"    "199.063249" "15.363928" "1996.029477" "39.84747"  "4953.276187"
 [5,] "2013-05"  "27.633188" "3.030127" "32.675746" "765.5369"   "221.793898" "13.232063" "2247.850876" "73.201747" "5425.804703"
 [6,] "2013-06"  "24.064953" "2.816781" "29.454347" "60.756462"  "201.765833" "13.698186" "2291.680871" "32.821853" "5271.431577"
 [7,] "2013-07"  "26.25563"  "2.657042" "15.540238" "95.12846"   "233.746903" "14.499091" "2359.924118" "33.763333" "5666.628083"
 [8,] "2013-08"  "26.85187"  "2.883294" "21.369248" "74.317362"  "180.045606" "15.545374" "1985.100494" "31.342921" "5557.632778"
 [9,] "2013-09"  "25.025515" "3.368449" "26.061924" "89.380055"  "211.352443" "12.323627" "2441.630301" "25.107398" "5558.266666"
[10,] "2013-10"  "34.040048" "3.249082" "49.352241" "128.44329"  "227.724296" "17.172523" "2131.788729" "28.489788" "5411.943251"
```

As you probably know, the names of those areas are available in `DataStructureMethod("DOT")$CL_COUNTERPART_AREA_DOT`.

Comment: This seems to be the right direction. Thank you. Nevertheless, when I try to extract specific countries, I got this error (slightly changing the last line of your code): `result <- as.data.frame(cbind(timeperiod = result.list[[1]]$Obs[[1]][['@TIME_PERIOD']],result))
result <- dplyr::select(result, "CA", "JP", "US", "PL", "TW", "MX", "BR", "HU", "SG", "ZA", "HK", 
                 "NZ", "RU", "CN", "CH", "KR", "ID", "NO", "U2", "AU", "DK", "GB", "SE", "TR")`. The error message is: `Error: Can't subset columns that don't exist.
x The column `TW` doesn't exist.`

Comment: I've tried this approach, using `databaseID`, `startdate`, and `enddate`: `countries = c("CA", "JP", "US", "PL", "TW", "MX", "BR", "HU", "SG", "ZA", "HK", 
          "NZ", "RU", "CN", "CH", "KR", "ID", "NO", "U2", "AU", "DK", "GB", "SE", "TR")

queryfilter <- list(CL_FREQ = "M", CL_AREA_DOT = countries, CL_INDICATOR_DOT = "TXG_FOB_USD", CL_COUNTERPART_AREA_DOT = "W00")
EXPORTS <- CompactDataMethod(databaseID, queryfilter, startdate, enddate, checkquery)

list2env(EXPORTS, .GlobalEnv)

XDF = do.call(what = cbind, args = Obs)

XDF <- XDF[ , -which(names(XDF) %in% c("@TIME_PERIOD"))]`

Comment: It doesn't look like the API returns data for "TW".

Comment: You're right. "U2" seems to be missing too. It's weird for Taiwan because it's available (https://data.imf.org/regular.aspx?key=61013712).

Answer (score 2):

You might want to create a list and combine together thanks to the `Reduce` function (or `purrr:::reduce`). I often come back to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8091303/simultaneously-merge-multiple-data-frames-in-a-list):

Assuming you have a list of `X.DF`s dataframe named `X_DF`, you can do:

```r
Reduce(function(dtf1, dtf2) merge(dtf1, dtf2, by = "i", all.x = TRUE),
        list_XDF)
```

or, if you prefer `tidyverse` syntax:

```r
list_XDF %>% purrr::reduce(left_join, by=c("@TIME_PERIOD"))
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It solves the problem from this part: `XDF <- dplyr::left_join(XDF.1, XDF.2, by=c("@TIME_PERIOD"))`. Do you have any ideas on how to extract the 25 countries from `EXPORTS`, without doing this for each of them: `XDF.1 <- EXPORTS$Obs[[1]]
XDF.2 <- EXPORTS$Obs[[2]]`

Comment: Does `list_XDF  <- lapply(1:25, function(i) EXPORTS$Obs[[i]])` work ?